# Ubuntu 20.04 not able to monitor disk usage via snmp

Tags: networking, 18.04, 20.04, disk-usage, snmp

I've been trying to get SNMP to work for OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9 on Ubuntu 20 and 22, for reference: https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9

When trying on Ubuntu 18 it does work. Ubuntu 18 uses SNMP version 5.7.3. whereas Ubuntu 20 uses 5.8.0 and Ubuntu 22 uses 5.9.0., I am not sure how relevant that is, but I'd just thought I'd put it alongside it.

.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9 is the only address I can't reach on Ubuntu 20 and 22, .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10/11 I can reach just fine.

The command I use to check the values on that address is as following:
`snmpwalk -v2c -c public -OnQU localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9`

Here's the `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` I've been using in all three scenarios:

```
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>

sysServices    72

master  agentx

agentaddress udp:161

view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021

rocommunity  public default -V systemonly
rocommunity6 public default -V systemonly

rouser authPrivUser authpriv -V systemonly
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong? Or what I could try to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Adding `includeAllDisks [percentage]` to the `snmpd.conf` resolved the issue.